# Problems with wordpress on mobile devices

Tags: android, html, css, wordpress

I'm having some troubles displaying my first websites on mobiles devices. When the device is vertical, the website background image does not fit the entire screen i've tried with the background-size: 100% 100% rule but does not work either. This is my css right now:

```
background-attachment: scroll;
background-image: url("http://qubik-design.co.nf/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/rsz_intro-bg4.jpg");
background-position: left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
```

The last trouble is the footer. It does not stick to the bottom of the screen even on some PC. This is the css:

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">

#colophon {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

I tried with bottom:0px but does not work and this is all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use code snippet in the question and reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Vishwanath Look, i can't reproduce the error because it's a error of the theme and i don't know what can be and i don't know too much css. I changed into custom-background because the background-image doesn't fit the width and i added the background-size but with the height didn't work. I was trying somethings in different sites of the css that firebug told me but didn't work and i posted the code up where i changed things. Thanks.

Comment: @Vishwanath You can see the errors here http://qubik-design.co.nf/ . I searched this errors but the common solutions didn't work and i was searching for a couple of days so I posted for help.

Comment: What do you really want to happen, image to stretch to fit to entire screen when in portrait mode. Do u want it to cover entire screen maintaining the aspect ratio of the image or stretch  to fit to entire screen?

Comment: If you want to stretch to fit the screen, then try giving height 100% to html and body.

Comment: @Vishwanath mmmm really i don't know what i want. I would like to try all the options and see what I like the most but if you see on mobile the website is a bit ugly because the heigth is in the middle of the screen. What would you advise me? If you want check out to the website. About the footer i want keep it down but sometimes even on some PC the footer is in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your background image fill the entire screen you can use [background-size: cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images#cover). You will also need to make the body 100% height.

```
body.custom-background {
    background-image: url('http://qubik-design.co.nf/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/rsz_intro-bg4.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

It, however, will not look right with the current background image. You might want to make this 2 images instead.

For the footer, assuming it is only for this site and you will not change the height, or you can change the CSS accordingly, you could make the page id 100% of the screen height and add a bottom padding that is at least as high as the footer.

```
#page {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding-bottom: 250px;
}
```

Then you can give the colofon an absolute positioning.

```
#colophon {
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it was really useful your help but the footer it's not too well (just in mobile devices) because if the page is more little than the screen with your css the footer keep down but it's not in a only page, i have to scroll when his content can be in one into the screen.

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe this is a more solid solution, but it will probably be a little more work to implement: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/